# "This operation requires an interactive window station" error when launching GUI via jenkins on aws windows instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a windows ec2 instance which runs a build server for a unity game, controlled by jenkins.

When running unity with the -batchMode command, I can make the game build successfully.

I'd like to run some automated tests inside unity, which require the physics system to be running, which can't happen in batch mode. If I remove that command line parameter, I get this error:

```
<I> Failed to get cursor position:
This operation requires an interactive window station.
```

I know the GPU is powerful enough to run the game - if I remote desktop in, then I can run it at 30fps.

How do I get my ec2 instance to run a "window station" to make this launch successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message specifies that running GUI is impossible without an
"interactive window station".
As the default installation of Jenkins is as a system service, and as system services
run inside a non-interactive window station, this is probably why you are getting the
error.

To have Jenkins running not as a service but as an application with
an interactive window station:

1. Stop and disable the Jenkins service in the Services applet:

   [image]
2. Run Jenkins via the Command Prompt : `java -jar jenkins.war`

   [image]

For a more detailed guide, check out the "Infrastructure" section of the Ranorex
[Jenkins integration blog](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/integrating-ranorex-automation-in-jenkins-continuous-integration-process/#infrastructure).

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914303/jenkins-ranorex-plugin-not-executing-test))

Comment: @tenpn: You posted a bounty to "draw more attention to this question". Now where are you?

Comment: I haven't had a chance yet to try this approach. I will do in the next week or so.

Comment: @tenpn: That will be too late for the bounty.

Comment: that's unfortunate, I can award the bounty because it's a detailed answer, and then hold on the tick until I've actually validated it.

Comment: I needed to drag the jnlp file into the windows startup folder per https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Agenttomasterconnections but then the connection worked. still yet to test unity on it it...